# Check box and Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, textjoin

I have a sheet with 6 check boxes, i have the below formula that will complete a Vlookup when the check box is ticked, what i now need to know how to do is adapt the formula to complete Vlookups when several check boxes are ticked, and then put the result of the vlookups into one cell.

This formula is the current method i am using but as you will see it only works when one check box is ticked and then populates the result into the one cell.

```
=IF(B2=TRUE,(VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet3!A2:B7,2,FALSE)),"")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Doesnt work, only populates one vlookup return not multiples in the same cell!

Comment: I have posted an answer, you could try the same and let me know if that works, its an assumption based because posting some sample or mocks up helps us to provide more precise and accurate solutions

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, since there is no sample or any mockup posted, I was not able to understand which sheet has what, so I am assuming this should satisfy as per the given conditions, if not please let me know, I will try to make the necessary changes.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,MAP(A2:A7,B2:B7,LAMBDA(x,y, FILTER(Sheet3!B1:B6,(Sheet3!A1:A6=x)*(y),""))))
```

---

- Using `MAP()` function to apply a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations for the two arrays to pass for its each element, the arrays here are `A2:A7` and `B2:B7` which are defined as `x` and `y` respectively.
- Within the above we are using `FILTER()` function to grab based on the **`include`** parameter which applies two conditions, if the names in `Sheet3` is equal to the one in `Sheet2` as in the example here as well as if the `CheckBoxes` are ticked. If these meets the conditions then returns the numbers in `Sheet3` for each respective names.
- Lastly, wrapping the output within `TEXTJOIN()` function with a delimiter comma to get desired output.

---

Comment: The above answer you have provided works, however is there a way to have the Vlookup results formatted into paragraphs?

Comment: Sorry I dont think you can format it as paragraphs since its a formula returned, you may need someother formulas to suit your needs.